# How can I run a Bash script every time is plugged an USB device?

Tags: 18.04, bash, usb

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I need to run a Bash script every time is plugged a new USB device (interdependently from the device type).

**PS:** I found other answers able to works for a specified USB device, but I need to works for ANY possible USB device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Start systemd .service from an udev rule**

`udev monitor` allows you to monitor kernel uevents and print the devpaths to the console, which can then be used by `udevadm info -a --path=''` to print all sysfs properties for all devices along the chain.

`udevadm monitor --environment --udev` lets you monitor environment variable set by udev events after the rule processing.

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-autorun.rules
```

```
# Start USB autorun systemd .service
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", \
TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="usb_autorun.service"
```

<sup>(dont forget to reload your rule `udevadm control --reload && udevadm trigger`).</sup>

...and */etc/systemd/system/usb_autorun.service*:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB Autorun.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/bin/usb_autorun.sh
```

Comment: hope this doesnt match too much.

Comment: I have to test it, but for the moment, thank you very much for the documentation ;)

Comment: `ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device"` was the most generic but still uniq  I could find.

Comment: Test just done. When I try to `enable` the `usb_autorun.service` I receive the `The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units)` error, and checking for the service status return `inactive`

Comment: no need to enable it just place it in `/etc/systemd/system` (its more like a wrapper for your script, in my case `/opt/bin/usb_autorun.sh`)

Comment: But my script is never executed. I just test plugging a new USB External HD, and adding `echo 'ok' > /var/log/test.log` and the log file is never created.

Comment: does it run with `systemctl start usb_autorun.service`

Comment: really strange, now all seems to works fine! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I developped a Python script that listens for specific devices and executes an action when the device is connected, eg:

```
pip install udev_monitor
udev_monitor.py --devices 0665:5161 --filters=usb --action /root/some_script.sh
```

The action will get as argument found device.

You can find the full sources [here](https://github.com/netinvent/udev_monitor)

There's also a systemd unit file and a configuration file example, so you can run a service monitoring a specific device.