# A udev rule for automatically executing rsync scrips is not working

Tags: bash, rsync, udev

I have written the following udev rule `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-Goprobackup.rules`

```sh
# when device /dev/sd* is added to the KERNEL with the UUID defined RUN the script
        
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="/dev/sd[b-z][!0-9]", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="57584A314541334A414C4535", RUN+="/usr/bin/gopro_autobackup.sh"
```

The script itself is as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

sleep 30

/usr/bin/sudo --user=sebthomas rsync -a --delete --ignore-existing /media/sebthomas/Gopro-Local/ /media/sebthomas/GoPro-Video-Backup/


aplay /usr/share/sounds/sound-icons/canary-long.wav
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. What's wrong with the udev rule that means it won't run the script? I have tried using ENV variables for other identifiers like UUID too and they also don't work.
2. How do I make the script execute `rsync` as root? The script works when running it in the terminal except for the `sudo` permission. `rsync` simply runs as the current bash user and I get the following output (including the audio):

   ```
   rsync: opendir "/media/sebthomas/Gopro-Local/lost+found" failed: Permission denied (13)
     IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
   rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) 
   [sender=3.1.3] Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/sound-icons/canary-long.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
   ```

This is how I pulled the `ID_SERIAL_SHORT`:

```
sebthomas@Ubuntu-Desktop:~$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdd | grep ID_SERIAL
E: ID_SERIAL=WD_Elements_10B8_57584A314541334A414C4535-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=57584A314541334A414C4535
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

**SOLUTION**

So this is what finally worked, huge thanks to bac0n for all the help (who doesn't love bac0n!)...

I have a udev rule:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/10-gopro_backup.service
```

Containing the following:

```sh
#run backup on mounting specific partition 

ACTION=="add", \
ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="679ECE115B048FC5", \ 
TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="gopro_backup.service"
```

Make sure you run `sudo udevadm control --reload && udevadm trigger` every time you make changes to this.

This runs the service `/etc/systemd/system/gopro_backup.service`

Containing the following:

```
[UNIT]
Description=Autorun backup of local gopro media

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gopro_backup.sh
```

This executes the script `/usr/bin/gopro_backup.sh`

Containing the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

sleep 60

rsync -a --delete --ignore-existing /media/sebthomas/Gopro-Local/ /media/sebthomas/Gopro-Backup/

aplay /usr/share/sounds/sound-icons/canary-long.wav
```

Make sure that you run `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gopro_backup.sh` after first creating this one.

The observant reader will notice I cleaned up the syntax and naming conventions a lot in this final version so the file names were effectively identical and the names for drive mount locations and labels followed te same format. This isn't essential but will really help checking for errors that will cause you a massive headache later on.

Thanks again to bac0n for the direction on this one!

Comment: ...some of the line got lost in copy&paste, you should not RUN script like that use TAG+="systemd" , ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="my.service" instead

Comment: dont use sudo systemd will run the service as root

Comment: I removed RUN and replaced it with 'TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="/usr/bin/gopro_autobackup.sh"' but still no dice. Any more thoughts?

Comment: also tried ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}=="/usr/bin/gopro_autobackup.sh"

Comment: no, it needs to be a /etc/systemd/system/my.service [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228950/script-run-by-udev-rule-fails/1228973#1228973)

Comment: SYSTEMD_WANTS runs it as a system service which you should (and SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS runs is as a user .service)

Comment: Your script is running when the device file is created, at which point it may not be mounted yet.

Comment: That's why there's a sleep 30 in the bash script. I'll try making it longer but the USB drive is pretty quick to mount. I don't think it will help though as the script just starts backing up to the unmounted local directory if the drive hasn't been mounted there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to match a device in this case a block device, then you should try to match the device as uniquely and late as possible (in your example `ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}` is part of multiple events, this will make your script run several times).

udevadm will allow you to monitor udev events:

```
udevadm monitor --environment --udev
```

Or kernel uevents:

```
udevadm monitor
```

You can also trigger these events by writing  to the uevent file in the /sys tree:

```
echo add > /sys/block/sdc/sdc1/uevent
```

<sup>prints either events or uevents, depending on which udevadm monitor is active.</sup>

How to trigger a specific partition using UUID.

```
ACTION=="add", \
ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="9AE4-6A76", \
TAG+="systemd", \
ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="gopro-backup@%E{ID_FS_UUID}.service"
```

<sup>Don't forget to reload your udev.rule.</sup>

/etc/systemd/system/gopro-backup@.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup action for GoPro

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/bin/gopro_backup.sh %i
```

<sup>You do not need to start or enable this .service.</sup>

An example how you can control your backup with a fstab entry (use: `lsblk /dev/sda -o +UUID` to list part uuid's):

```
UUID=<uuid> /media/GoPro vfat defaults,noauto 0 0
```

<sup>(if you comment this entry the backup want run).</sup>

/opt/bin/gopro_backup.sh (very simple):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[[ -n $1 ]] && uuid=$1 || exit 1

if ! findmnt -f --fstab UUID=$uuid &>/dev/null
then
   systemd-cat -t GoPro -p 4 <<< \
   "Warning: Device entry is missing, check your fstab."
   exit 1
fi

[[ -b /dev/disk/by-uuid/$uuid ]] || exit 1

# Retry 5 times.
while :; do
   if (($((++b)) > 5)); then
      exit 1
   elif findmnt -f UUID=$uuid &>/dev/null; then
      break
   else
      mount UUID=$uuid || sleep 5
   fi
done

source=$(findmnt UUID=$uuid -nfo TARGET)

mkdir -p /opt/backup/GoPro/video
rsync -a --delete --ignore-existing "$source/" /opt/backup/GoPro/video

# Success ?
if (($?)); then
   systemd-cat -t GoPro -p 3 <<< \
   "Error: Backup: Failed."
else
   systemd-cat -t GoPro -p 6 <<< \
   "Info: Backup: successful."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Still no result yet with changing the trigger to a DEVLINK by uuid. A few things that might hep though:

Comment: when watching the output of udevadm monitor I don't see any output for add events that relate to /dev/sd*. Is this because the devices already exist there so there is no need to add them? There are loads of other add events the final one being `KERNEL[55807.559618] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:65-fuseblk (bdi)
 ` should i look at using some of these instead as they match to UDEV add events too?

Comment: The fact that no `/dev/sd*` add event on the kernel is backed up by the fact that I have just changed my syntax to point directly at `/dev/sde1` in the udev rule where the drive is currently being mounted and it still didn't execute the script

Comment: I know thtats not clean long term a the device may change whit other drive mounts and reboots etc but thought it would be a good test of the function. Is there a more suitable trigger to use for the device being detected by udev?

Comment: if you have an uuid your device is allready triggered ... remember to reload your rule when you have made some changes to it with `udevadm control --reload && udevadm trigger` before starting udevadm monitor last disconnect'n'connect.

Comment: with systemd you can trigger your script with `systemd start gopro_backup.service`

Comment: Thanks again, just checking what may be obvious abvain sorry but in the answer are you saying that `ENV{DEVLINKS}=="/dev/disk/by-uuid/9AE4-6A76", \
TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="gopro_backup.service"` is the entire udev rule. no need for the `ACTION` and `KERNEL` parts?

Comment: changed the rule, noticed if you have multiple link you need to match with wildcards link. so the new rule will work better, did some change to the script ... dont think you can play sound like that (missed [Unit] on the service lost in copy paste)

Comment: I'll try it later. I did run `systemd start gopro_backup.service` and it failed (`too many [somethings]`) . But when I ran it as `systemctl start gopro_backup.service` it ran the script fine. I think it's close now but it'll have to wait for now...

Comment: you probably have a space in your target path, when you need to qoute it

Comment: Thanks bac0n. got it working!! Found a small little syntax error when adding the `ACTION=="add", \` line intot the udev rule and then output the whole backup to the directory before the disk was mounted to it because I'd removed the sleep function of the script but it is all now working. I'll add the final solution to my original post for others to see what worked exactly and for your interest.

Comment: I jumped the gun.... It works now but it still needs a few more tweaks. I runs ever time a device is added to the system and it keeps gopro_backup.service running indefinitely