# I get an error when copying files to a USB drive with my script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to copy my data to a USB drive and get an error message.

The reason is that when copying all data I get a "/" at the beginning.

Does anyone know why this is?

Below you can see my code:

```
if ( [ -e $Dirname ] && [ -e /dev/sdb1 ] )
then
cp /home/jason/tmp/*_backup* /$Dirname
rm -r /home/jason/tmp/*_backup*
    echo "Your data was successfully copied."

else
    echo "Your USB stick is not connected or not mounted."
fi
$Dirname < /home/jason/Programs/Script/dirname_backup2usb.txt
```

And the parameter that i am giving to $Dirname is:

`#!/bin/bash`

`/media/xyz`

Comment: Is this even on Ubuntu? You have not said.

Comment: Hi David, yes. It is Ubuntu.

Comment: If you’re passing `/media/xyz` as the parameter, the slash in `/$Dirname` may be messing things up 

Comment: Thank you @matigo, it was for the slash. But It says now all the data has been successfully copied. but they will not be present in the destination directory.
Am I doing something wrong with PASSING?

Comment: @matigo because when i am copying these with the command cp without passing the adress, it works well.

Comment: Don't use *copy* and *remove* (at least not without some form of verification), if the *copy* fails, it's still going to remove your backup. `mv` or `rsync` is probably a better choice.

Comment: @bac0n Thank you. I recognized that every time all backups are deleted although the process failed.

Comment: maybe this [example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231737/a-udev-rule-for-automatically-executing-rsync-scrips-is-not-working/1231839#1231839) can work as a foundation for your script instead, starting from "An example how you can..."

Answer (score 1):

Testing for `/dev/sdb1` does not guarantee anything. You would like to identify the mountpoint of the file system on the USB drive. Try with the a command line with `lsblk`, for example

```
lsblk -f
```

or I think better, with

```
lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,HOTPLUG,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,MODEL | grep -v '/snap/'
```

You can make an alias to make it easier:

```
alias mylsblk="lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,HOTPLUG,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,MODEL | grep -v '/snap/'"
```

and edit it into your `~/.bashrc` file near the other aliases. Run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and you can start using it:

```
$ mylsblk
NAME          SIZE HOTPLUG FSTYPE LABEL           MOUNTPOINT          MODEL
sda         238,5G       0                                            SanDisk SD6SB1M2
├─sda1        500M       0 ntfs   System
├─sda2      139,4G       0 ntfs   Windows
├─sda3       1000M       0 ntfs   Recovery
├─sda4          1K       0
├─sda5       89,7G       0 ext4   lubionic        /
└─sda6          8G       0 swap                   [SWAP]
sdb           3,7T       0                                            WDC WD4002FYYZ-0
├─sdb1        510M       0 ext4   boot-nvme-focal
├─sdb2         30G       0 ext4   xubufocal-hdd
├─sdb5          1M       0
├─sdb6        100G       0 ext4   studio12.04
├─sdb7        3,5T       0 ext4   multimed-2      /media/multimed-2
└─sdb8          5G       0 swap
sdc            15G       1                                            Transcend 16GB
└─sdc1         15G       1 vfat   KEEP_ME         /media/nio/KEEP_ME
sr0          1024M       1                                            DVD-RW DH16AESH
nvme0n1     232,9G       0                                            KINGSTON SA2000M8250G
├─nvme0n1p1 232,9G       0 ext4   nvme-focal
└─nvme0n1p2     1M       0
```

In the example from my computer there are many drives and even more partitions. But now you can see that HOTPLUG is 1 for `/dev/sdc`, and you can see the size and model, to make it easy to identify. So in this case you should copy to the mountpoint of the FAT file system `/media/nio/KEEP_ME`.

Comment: thank you @sudodus for your detailed answer. 
I'm going to try it. My biggest problem is now, that i cant pass or redirect the directory for copying the files. Can you see in my Code where is the failure is?

Comment: I'm sorry, @H.B., but I don't understand your shellscript. it is very far from how I would do the programming. I think you must explain in words what you want to do (where you have your original data), Please run an lsblk command similar to what I show in the answer. Copy and paste the output from the command into the original question. Indent each line by 4 spaces to render it as code. Otherwise it is difficult to read. When I see the output I will understand more and I should be able to help you.

Comment: @H.B., Have you used command lines in a terminal window before? You can copy and paste between your web browser and the command line window. Press the Enter key to execute the command line.